# how to make visible a radiobutton by the selection of combobox items?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a combobox with 3 items and two radio buttons. If I select item1 radioButton1 should be made visible and the second should be hidden. If item2 is selected the process should be vice-versa and by selecting item3 both radio buttons should be made visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="combo">
            <ComboBoxItem x:Name="item1" Content="item1" IsSelected="True"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem x:Name="item2" Content="item2"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem x:Name="item3" Content="item3"></ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <RadioButton Content="1">
                <RadioButton.Style>
                    <Style>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, ElementName=item1}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="RadioButton.Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, ElementName=item1}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="RadioButton.Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, ElementName=item3}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="RadioButton.Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </RadioButton.Style>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Content="2">
                <RadioButton.Style>
                    <Style>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, ElementName=item2}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="RadioButton.Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, ElementName=item2}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="RadioButton.Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, ElementName=item3}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="RadioButton.Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </RadioButton.Style>
            </RadioButton>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are coding in c#, You can use a switch-case branch in comboBoxSelectedIndexChanged event function. For the visibility, the Visible class should be used, what you can control with a Boolean value.
Something like this in C#(Not tested):

```
void ComboBox1SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Object selectedItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
        switch (selectedItem.ToString())
        {
            case "item1":
                radioButton1.Visible = true;
                radioButton2.Visible = false;
                break;
            case "item2":
                radioButton1.Visible = false;
                radioButton2.Visible = true;
                break;
            case "item3":
                radioButton1.Visible = true;
                radioButton2.Visible = true;
                break;
            default:
                radioButton1.Visible = false;
                radioButton2.Visible = false;
                break;
        }
}
```